# Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `localtime'

Tags: ruby, logstash

I am using logstash 2.1.3,I want to show the @timestamp field in my timezone, like "@timestamp" => "2015-03-09T04:24:29.718+08:00", I try to using ruby conversion in filter.

```
filter 
  {

     ruby {

       code => "event['@timestamp'] =  
            event['@timestamp'].localtime('+08:00')"

    }

}
```

but i got the error msg as below,

> Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `localtime' for "2016-04-29T00:40:51.926Z":LogStash::Timestamp {:level=>:error}

Any help is welcome to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call `localtime` on a String (the result of `event['@timestamp']`, and it should instead be called on a Time object.  You'll need to parse that String into a Time object.

Check out this irb session:

```
> require 'date'
true
> fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z'
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z"
> s = "2016-04-29T00:40:51.926Z"
"2016-04-29T00:40:51.926Z"
> localtime_as_string = DateTime.strptime(s,fmt).to_time.localtime('+08:00').strftime(fmt)
"2016-04-29T08:40:51.926+0800"
```

In your case, you could use:

```
require 'date'
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z'
s = event['@timestamp'].to_s
tz = '+08:00'
event['@timestamp'] =  DateTime.strptime(s, fmt).to_time.localtime(tz).strftime(fmt)
```

On further examination, it looks from the output like `event['@timestamp']` contains an instance of Logstash::Timestamp.  I looked at that API (https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/logstash-core-event/lib/logstash/timestamp.rb) and it looks like there is a publicly accessible `time` method that I presume returns an instance of `Time`.  If that is the case, then the above will not work but this may:

```
require 'date'
# For fmt you may also be able to use Logstash::Timestamp::ISO8601_STRFTIME
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z'
time = event['@timestamp'].time
tz = '+08:00'
event['@timestamp'] = time.localtime(tz).strftime(fmt)
```

However, are you sure you want to replace `event['@timestamp']`?  Another approach would be to use it for display but not modify the original variable.  This might be safer because if the variable is used elsewhere it will not be known which of the 2 it is.